# To display a query result having join using JSTL in JSP

Tags: mysql, eclipse, apache, jsp, jstl

I am facing a trouble in displaying my query result as it contains JOINS.

```
<sql:query var="ApplicationDetails" dataSource="${myDS}">
        SELECT a.idApplication idApplication,a.ConfigID ConfigId,a.App_Origin App_Origin,a.ApplicationName ApplicationName, a.Description Description,b.ownername businessOwner,d.ownername TechnicalOwner, e.ownername DomainOwner
        FROM application a, owner b, owner d, owner e
        where a.idbusinessowner=b.idowner
        and a.idtechnicalowner=d.idowner
        and a.iddomainowner=e.idowner 
        and a.ApplicationName='<%=request.getParameter("AppName")%>';
</sql:query>
```

I need to display Application details along with Application's Business, Domain and Technical owner extracted from the same table 'Owners' hence, I have used join thrice.
Following is my JSTL code

```
<c:forEach var="application a, owner b, owner d, owner e" items="${ApplicationDetails.rows}">

            Application Name : <c:out value="${ApplicationDetails.a.ApplicationName}"/>

            <br>Application id: <c:out value="${ApplicationDetails.a.idApplication}"/>

            <br>Config ID: <c:out value="${ApplicationDetails.a.ConfigID}"/>

            <br>VHA Origin: <c:out value="${ApplicationDetails.a.App_Origin}"/>       

            <br>Description: <p><c:out value="${ApplicationDetails.a.Description}"/>

            <br>Owners<br>

            <table>
            <tr><td>Domain owner</td>
                <td><c:out value="${ApplicationDetails.e.ownername}"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Business owner</td>
                <td><c:out value="${ApplicationDetails.b.ownername}"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Technical owner</td>
                <td><c:out value="${ApplicationDetails.d.ownername}"/></td></tr>
            </table>
</c:forEach>
```

When I run the above code in eclipse i get following error in console

**HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /DisplayApplicationDetails.jsp at line 29**

root cause

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'a' not found on type org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.ResultImpl
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:214)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:191)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:300)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:81)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:182)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:919)
    org.apache.jsp.DisplayApplicationDetails_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f0(DisplayApplicationDetails_jsp.java:269)
    org.apache.jsp.DisplayApplicationDetails_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(DisplayApplicationDetails_jsp.java:198)
    org.apache.jsp.DisplayApplicationDetails_jsp._jspService(DisplayApplicationDetails_jsp.java:133)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.43 logs.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple variables defined in the `var`attribute of `<c:forEach>` tag. You also can't use the SQL syntax `<table-alias>.<column-name>` to refer to your resultset properties in EL expressions.

Your `<c:forEach>` JSP block should be like

```
<c:forEach var="AppRow" items="${ApplicationDetails.rows}">

        Application Name : <c:out value="${AppRow.ApplicationName}"/>

        <br>Application id: <c:out value="${AppRow.idApplication}"/>

        <br>Config ID: <c:out value="${AppRow.ConfigID}"/>

        <br>VHA Origin: <c:out value="${AppRow.App_Origin}"/>       

        <br>Description: <p><c:out value="${AppRow.Description}"/>

        <br>Owners<br>

        <table>
        <tr><td>Domain owner</td>
            <td><c:out value="${AppRow.DomainOwner}"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Business owner</td>
            <td><c:out value="${AppRow.businessOwner}"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Technical owner</td>
            <td><c:out value="${AppRow.TechnicalOwner}"/></td></tr>
        </table>
</c:forEach>
```

Notice, how the `var` attribute uses only one variable name `AppRow` to point to a row in the resultset as you iterate over it within the loop. And, the syntax `<varName>.<columnAlias>` in the `${EL}` expressions to pull the resultset's column values.